# Display total number of pages using CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages

Tags: objective-c, pdf, ios6

I want to display total number of pages in pdf on navigation bar

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];

totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(path);

PageViewController *page = [[PageViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];

page.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view addSubview:page.view];

[self addChildViewController:page];

 [self displaycurrentIndex:1];
}

- (void) displaycurrentIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {
self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                              @"Page %u of %u",
                                              currentIndex,
                                              totalPages];
  }
```

but on the nav bar it shows 1 of 0.

whereas it should 1 of totalpages in pdf.

EDIT:

i am not using URL statement like this

```
 CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("paper.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
```

In my case i m using

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

that is why it is not getting total number of pages in pdf. How can i get total number of pages in pdf using my case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages()` expects a `CGPDFDocumentRef` as argument, not the path
to the file.

The following code should work to open the PDF document at the given `path` and
get the number of pages:

```
NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl);
int totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocument);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);
```

(`(__bridge CFURLRef)` is only necessary if you compile with ARC.)

Comment: Edited little bit NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pages" ofType:@"pdf"];NSURL *pdfurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfurl); - (void) displaycurrentIndex:(NSUInteger)currentIndex {
    
        
   
 self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                  @"Page %i of %i",
                                                  currentIndex,
                                                 CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)];
}  and now its working . thanks for help.

Comment: @user1120133: You are welcome. (Just remember to *release* the PDF document somewhere.)

Comment: I m using ARC. it will release pdf document automatically.

Comment: @user1120133: ARC does *not* release Core Foundation objects such as a CGPDFDocumentRef.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for sharing. I will release then. Again thanks for your time and help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(path);
```

Huh? You need to pass in a `CGPDFDocumentRef`, not a filesystem path.

([Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000958-CH1g-F17191))

Comment: i know previously i had CGPDFDocumentRef as pdf like this - (void) displayPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber {
 self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:
         @"Page %u of %u", 
         pageNumber, 
         CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)];
}  but still it is not showing pdf total number of pages